# combobox / DB error?

Tags: combobox, oledb

I have this problem where room_type_id is set to 1 (the id of "Standard hotel rate", on table tbl_Room) even though I chose "Dormitory Type Room", whose id is equivalent to 2.

This is my code

```
        cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=xleira-haven\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MegikoHMS;Uid=sa; Pwd=b1admin;");
        OleDbCommand cmdRead = new OleDbCommand("select * from tbl_RoomType", cn);
        InitializeComponent();
        cn.Open();

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdRead);

        dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        cbRoomType.DisplayMember = "room_type_name";
        cbRoomType.ValueMember = "room_type_id";
        cbRoomType.DataSource = dt;

        if (cbRoomType.Text == dt.Rows[0]["room_type_name"].ToString())
        {
            x = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["room_type_name"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a declaration of your 'x' variable, but you are trying to do an int.parse() against the room_type_name... shouldn't that be the room_type_id